# Allow user to move up to five spaces in Maze game

Tags: c++, maze

I'm trying to allow the user to enter something like 'w2' or 'w5' and move that many spaces in the up direction in the maze. Currently the problem is, whenever the console see's that a 'w' character is entered, it will move one space up, no matter what comes after it. It will also say "Not a valid move" as you'll see is the default case.

I think this would be a fairly easy thing to implement but I'm just doing it wrong. I tried simply doing `moved = floor->move_to_x_y (*this, -2, 0)` but that doesn't work.

Here is the function I'm working with:

```
void Player::move (Game & game)
{   
char c;
Floor * floor;
bool    moved = false;

floor = game.get_curr_floor();
do
{   cout << "Enter move: ";
    cin >> c;
    switch (c)
    {
    case 'w':
        moved = floor->move_to_x_y (*this, -1, 0);
        break;
    case 'a':
        moved = floor->move_to_x_y (*this, 0, -1);
        break;
    case 's':
        moved = floor->move_to_x_y(*this, 1, 0);
        break;
    case 'd':
        moved = floor->move_to_x_y(*this, 0, 1);
        break;
    case 'w2':
        moved = floor->move_to_x_y (*this, -2, 0); //testing moving 2
    case 'w3':
        moved = floor->move_to_x_y (*this, -3, 0); //testing moving 3
    default:
        cout << "Not a valid move" << endl;
    }
}
while (! moved);
}
```

Here is the move_to_x_y function:

```
bool Floor::move_to_x_y (Character & character, int x_adj, int y_adj)
{   
char save_next;
int x, y;

x = character.get_x();
y = character.get_y();
if (! legal_move(x + x_adj, y + y_adj))
    return false;
save_next = tiles[x+x_adj][y+y_adj];
tiles[x+x_adj][y+y_adj] = character.get_sym();
tiles[x][y] = ' ';
character.set_position (x+x_adj, y+y_adj);
cout << "Moved " << character.get_sym() << " to " << x+x_adj << "," << y+y_adj << endl;
return true;
}
```

I appreciate all the help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

switch (c)
    {
    case 'w':

The single ' means that the entry is a single character. Therefore, you cannot have a character of 'w2'  Thus you **only** get the first character that you entered. Enter the values into a character array (c[]) use c[0] as the direction and c[1] as the number of spaces.

Additionally since you are reading into a character, your cin only gets the first character.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you get the input as a charater:

```
char c;

...
...
    cin >> c;
...
...
```

This only allows the storage of a single character. To represent multiple characters you either have to change chat to std::string which will require the enter key to be pressed, or you or you need to memorize the previous key-press and handle it on the next key press... for example: if last key press == 'd' and current key press = '2' then move down 2 steps ... Both are not ideal really. What is your actual requirements of your user interface? perhaps there is an easier/better user interaction method which would help solve the issue.

Based on feed back, something like follows:

```
int main()
{
    std::string cmd;

    do
    {
        // Input a string
        std::cin >> cmd;

        // Number of moves to make
        int moves = 1;
        int xDir = 0;
        int yDir = 0;

        // Behavoir based on length of input is different
        switch (cmd.size())
        {
        case 2:
            // Number of moves present, override default moves
            if (cmd[1] < '1' || cmd[1] > '5')
                continue;

            // Valid, update moves and fall thu to get direction
            moves = cmd[1] - '0';

        case 1:
            // Deal with the direction
            switch (cmd[0])
            {
            case 'a':
                xDir = -1;
                break;
            case 'd':
                xDir = 1;
                break;
            case 'w':
                yDir = -1;
                break;
            case 's':
                yDir = 1;
                break;
            default:
                // Invalid input
                continue;
            }

            // If we are here we have a valid move count and direction
            std::cout << "xdir = " << xDir*moves << ", ydir = " << yDir*moves << std::endl;
        }
    }
    while (cmd != "q");
}
```

We input a string now. If the length of the string is one character we assume a default of 1 step. If its two characters we take the second character and assume its the number of steps. Additional complication there is just for validation and error handling.

Comment: The requirement is to allow the user to enter either a 'w' or 'w2', w3, etc. They can also enter a s and d with a2, s3, d5, etc. as possible inputs. So essentially 1-5 spaces per turn, max 5. Thanks!